# Convert htacces to nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to rewrite the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|ttf)$ index.php
```

Update: I'm looking for an answer without if statement because of performance. if is evil!

Comment: `# nginx configuration location / { if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|ttf)$ /index.php; } }` maybe this.

Comment: Ah my question wasn't complete. I'm looking for an answer without if statement because of performance. if is evil!

Comment: this will help: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: Updating user question with details from comments.